# How can we determine a external user from the list of users in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i would like to know among all the users present in groups of sharepoint. Who is an external user and who is internal.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by external/internal user?

If you think of a Sharepoint site's group you will have to scroll to web.Groups

```
SPGroup group = web.Groups.GetByName("YOUR GROUP NAME");
foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
{
    // check if it's your user
}
```

If it is to check simple access to web's :

```
if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
```

And at last if you think of checking all existing users for a property external/internal you might want to use the Client Object Model to speed up your query otherwise you will have to browse all groups and users: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx